# XRdp disconnects immediately after successful connection from Windows 10 to Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, xrdp

I'm new to Linux so I'm not sure what is going on exactly but I'm remotely connecting to my Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Rdp connects successfully but then immediately closes the connection before giving me the chance to get to the login screen. I reinstalled the os and what is perplexing to me is that I was able to get it working before but now it is crashing. What I have noticed however is that when I run sudo startx before when it was working it kept the process running but now when I run that same command it immediately closes. I have attached screenshots of what I used to see and the output for what I'm seeing when I run sudo startx. I also included the error messages I'm seeing in the startx log

[image]

[image]

```
[  1050.999] (EE) Failed to load module "ast" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1051.139] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  1051.140] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
```

Comment: you may need to install a session-manager and a desktop environment. do you ? and btw you don't need sudo to run startx, just run it as your login user.

Comment: @dominix When I run it as my login user I get this error:

Only console users are allowed to run the X server

Comment: xrdp is just a service that provide rdp-protocol connectivity, it is your responsibility to give it a working X-server, that's why I recommend installing a displays-manager and a session-manager that gives user the ability to open session on Xorg. Once your user can open a Xorg session, he can open an xrdp session.